# Graph structure on graph homomorphisms

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, terminology, function-spaces

Let $G$ and $H$ be directed graphs. I want to form the following new graph $N$:

- The vertices of $N$ are the [graph homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism) from $G$ to $H$;
- Given $f,g:G\to H$, there is an edge from $f$ to $g$ if and only if for all vertices $x$ of $G$, there is an edge of $H$ from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$.

(Note that this does not use the edges of $G$ in the construction.)

My question is: is this construction known? If yes, how is it called, and where can I read more about it?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321897/is-mathrmgraph-cartesian-closed may be of interest

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a name for this construction but it is adjoint to the ["Cartesian product"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) of directed graphs (warning: despite the name, this is **not** the categorical product in the category of directed graphs).  That is, writing $[G,H]$ for your graph of homomorphisms from $G$ to $H$, there is a natural bijection between homomorphisms $G\to [H,K]$ and homomorphisms $G\mathbin{\square}H\to K$ where $\square$ denotes the Cartesian product.  This makes the category of directed graphs a closed symmetric monoidal category with respect to the Cartesian product.

Comment: Is there a reference for $[H,-]$ to be the right adjoint of the Cartesian product? Or is this folklore?

Comment: @BertLindenhovius: I don't know a reference.  I noticed it on my own a few years ago but I imagine it is somewhere in the literature.  The proof is very simple, you just unwind the definitions.